# Bootstrap rows not the same size

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem trying to create a scrollable timeline. The timeline itself is great but the rows following it are not the right width. How can I solve this?

The code is originally in Angular but I created a simpler plnkr that shows the problem...

http://plnkr.co/edit/lQkSP6ahgKH7GPdzld5r?p=preview

```
<div style="overflow-x: auto; width: auto;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">Timeline</div>
        <div class="col-10" style="display: flex; padding: 0;">
            <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap; box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #cecece;" *ngFor="let h of firstHalfDayHours">
                <span style="min-width: 82px; text-align: center">{{h}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="col-2">Worker</div>
        <div class="col-10" style="background-color: black;padding: 0;">Test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your second `row` will not match up with your first `row` because you have a `min-width`. what you can do is add that `min-width` inside the second `row`

Comment: I have the min-width on every time element so the times wouldn't get smashed together. How would you add the min-width to the other row?